# Why can canard wings not be used in all sonic aircraft despite their high control?

Tags: general-aviation, canard, folding-wings

As Canard serves two purposes; it improves aircraft control, also contributes to lift, replacing the horizontal stabilizer and - theoretically - reducing overall drag.

Comment: What do you mean by *sonic*?

Comment: Canard is only more efficient on aerodynamically *unstable* designs. We have a detailed explanation why somewhere around the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The forward canard does not replace the horizontal stabilizer, it actually forces a larger one for the same directional stability$^1$.  It is also less efficient than the main wing at producing lift, essentially re-creating a biplane$^2$.

Studying the progression of the Wright designs (and others) sheds light on why canards fell out of favor and more conventional tractor designs with pitch control aft became the norm after 1910.

The early canard designs were particularly dangerous when *both* wings stalled, leading to an unrecoverable nose up descent.  Interestingly, when early planes only could get a few feet off the ground, this type of stall was favorable because it tended to produce less damage than crashing nose first.

$^1$ canards can be used with delta wings, which are very stable in pitch

$^2$ positive lift from a canard could produce some fuel savings at cruise if the rear horizontal stabilizer/stabilator is set at 0 degrees and the wing is set at optimal AoA.  Essentially, the **elevator** is taken off the back, where it usually produces *downforce*, and is put on the front, where it can produce *up force*.  The benefit must be balanced with extra weight and complexity.

Answer (score 1):

They can be used on any aircraft designed for canards.

Retrofitting “all” supersonic aircraft with canards would be impractical for many reasons.